# How do i deal with error about Permission denied with gzip / cpio?

Tags: linux, embedded, busybox

I found the error when I attempt to type for zipping my rootfs(by busybox)

```
 sudo find . | cpio -H newc -o | gzip > rootfs.img.gz
```

and error message is

```
bash: rootfs.img.gz: Permission denied
```

and i rootfs.img.gz file isn't yet so i cant attempt to give "chmod + x" to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your [gzip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) syntax is incorrect, no need to use redirect sign and try to use `&&`. Try below:

```
sudo find . && cpio -H newc -o && gzip rootfs.img.gz
```

Comment: thanks. 
But i solved this problem by switching users. (sudo su)
Thank you for reply :)